# Spied Service Does Not Behave as Expected

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

Strap in folks, this is a code heavy one. I tried to keep it at a minimum but I do not see how to diagnose this one without some concrete examples.

I have written the following mock factory for a user service in my angular app. We use the `karma` tester runner and `jasmine` testing framework.

In case it matters, here are all our `karma` and jasmine`` testing dependencies

```
"karma": "4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.3.1",
"karma-trx-reporter": "0.3.0",

"@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
"jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
```

**The Mock Factory**

```
import {of, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {CurrentUserModel} from '../models/api-data-models/current-user-model';

export class UserServiceMockFactory {
  public static createUserServiceMock(jasmineSpyOn: any, jasmineSpyOnProperty: any, initialCurrentUserValue?: CurrentUserModel) {

    const currentUserStub = {
      // "as any" cast is essential here.
      // It allows us to set valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter to values that are not of type CurrentUserModel.
      // Most common use case would be an error
      valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter: !!initialCurrentUserValue ? initialCurrentUserValue as any : null,
      currentUserGetterThrows: false,

      get currentUser() {
        return !this.currentUserGetterThrows
          ? of(this.valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter)
          : throwError(this.valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter);
      },

      currentUserGetSpy: null, // spy field to assert calls upon currentUser getter

      flushCurrentUser() {
      },

      getUserBySearchTerm(term) {
      }
    };

    currentUserStub.currentUserGetSpy = jasmineSpyOnProperty(currentUserStub, 'currentUser', 'get').and.callThrough();

    jasmineSpyOn(currentUserStub, 'flushCurrentUser');
    jasmineSpyOn(currentUserStub, 'getUserBySearchTerm');

    return currentUserStub;
  }
}
```

Its intention is to provide a nice pre-mocked instance of the user service with all the spies a user could want to assert, and the option to pipe through a different user object by setting the `valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter`.

I have written the following test, and it succeeds just as I would expect.

```
it('should return new value if valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter changed, non-null initialization', () => {
  const expectedCurrentUser = new CurrentUserModel({
    id: '123',
    login: 'jdoe',
    isMaintenanceAndOperations: true,
    isExcluder: true,
    isSupport: true,
    isImpersonator: true,
    isViewAll: true,
    initiators: [],
    name: 'John Doe'
  });

  const userService = UserServiceMockFactory.createUserServiceMock(spyOn, spyOnProperty, new CurrentUserModel({
    id: '123_a',
    login: 'jdoe_a',
    isMaintenanceAndOperations: false,
    isExcluder: false,
    isSupport: false,
    isImpersonator: false,
    isViewAll: false,
    initiators: [],
    name: 'John Doe_a'
  }));
  userService.valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter = expectedCurrentUser;
  userService.currentUser
    .subscribe(cu => expect(cu).toEqual(expectedCurrentUser),
      () => fail('should not reach here'));
});
```

However, when it comes time to use it in a real life test it ... falls apart. I wrote the following minimum amount of code to isolate the failure

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {UserService} from '../http/user.service';
import {CurrentUserModel} from '../models/api-data-models/current-user-model';
import {UserServiceMockFactory} from './user-service-mock-factory';

describe('When Injected, Mock Behavior Seems to Fail', () => {

  let userService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{
        provide: UserService,
        useValue: UserServiceMockFactory.createUserServiceMock(spyOn, spyOnProperty,
          new CurrentUserModel({
            id: '123',
            login: 'jdoe',
            isMaintenanceAndOperations: true,
            isExcluder: true,
            isSupport: true,
            isImpersonator: true,
            isViewAll: true,
            initiators: [],
            name: 'John Doe'
          }))
      }]
    });

    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
  });

  it('should succeed but fails :(', () => {
    const expectedUser = new CurrentUserModel({
      id: '123_a',
      login: 'jdoe_a',
      isMaintenanceAndOperations: false,
      isExcluder: false,
      isSupport: false,
      isImpersonator: false,
      isViewAll: false,
      initiators: [], 
      name: 'John Doe_a'
    });

    userService.valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter = expectedUser;

    userService.currentUser.subscribe(cu => {
      expect(cu).toEqual(expectedUser);
    });
  });

});
```

It fails with the following message

```
Expected $.id = '123' to equal '123_a'.
Expected $.login = 'jdoe' to equal 'jdoe_a'.
Expected $.isMaintenanceAndOperations = true to equal false.
Expected $.isExcluder = true to equal false.
Expected $.isSupport = true to equal false.
Expected $.isImpersonator = true to equal false.
Expected $.isViewAll = true to equal false.
Expected $.name = 'John Doe' to equal 'John Doe_a'.
```

It appears that whenever the mock service is use to supplant a real one, it fails to ever change the value returned from `currentUser`, even when its backing field is very obviously changed.

The odd thing I found, is that I can get it to behave as expected by modifying the `UserServiceMockFactory` to be slightly different. Now, instead of making a generic object, spying upon that, then returning it, I implemented what seems to be an identical class, new up an instance thereof, spy on that instance, and voilà! Works as expected.

My main questions are:

Why does the original code behave differently when supplanting an actual service?

Why does the new version work as expected when supplanting an actual service?

**The Mock Factory that Works**

```
import {of, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {CurrentUserModel} from '../models/api-data-models/current-user-model';

class CurrentUserStub {
  valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter: any;
  currentUserGetterThrows = false;

  constructor(init?) {
    this.valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter = !!init ? init as any : null;
  }

  get currentUser() {
    return !this.currentUserGetterThrows
      ? of(this.valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter)
      : throwError(this.valuePipedThroughCurrentUserGetter);
  }

  currentUserGetSpy = null;

  // spy field to assert calls upon currentUser getter

  flushCurrentUser() {
  }

  getUserBySearchTerm(term) {
  }
}

export class UserServiceMockFactory {
  public static createUserServiceMock(jasmineSpyOn: any, jasmineSpyOnProperty: any, initialCurrentUserValue?: CurrentUserModel) {

    const currentUserStub = new CurrentUserStub(initialCurrentUserValue);

    currentUserStub.currentUserGetSpy = jasmineSpyOnProperty(currentUserStub, 'currentUser', 'get').and.callThrough();

    jasmineSpyOn(currentUserStub, 'flushCurrentUser');
    jasmineSpyOn(currentUserStub, 'getUserBySearchTerm');

    return currentUserStub;
  }
}
```